# Translation in AngularJS does not work

Tags: angularjs, typescript

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    urlTemplate: '/api/translation/{lang}'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('fr');
```

does not work properly.
In my API the result is:

```
/api/translation/en:
    {"INPUT":"TITLE","OUTPUT":"H2"}

/api/translation/fr:    
    {"INPUT":"TITLE","OUTPUT":"H1"}
```

The advertisement in console:

> angular.js:13236 pascalprecht.translate.$translateSanitization: No sanitization strategy has been configured. This can have serious security implications.

Comment: $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters');

Comment: result : {{ 'TITLE' | translate }}  :/

Comment: I guess your parameter is `INPUT` and should be translated to TITLE, so `{{ 'TITLE' | translate }}` doesn't make sense here.
Anyway you should provide your code to understand where the problem is

Comment: i have change my code api to :
public object GetFR()
        {
            return new { TITLE = "H1" };
        }

        [HttpGet("en.json")]
        public object GetEN()
        {
            return new { TITLE = "H2" };
        }
and i have the same problem

Comment: Code formatting & some language improvements